# Create trigger error: invalid syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

SQL query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_newuser_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_newuser
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tbl_seq VALUES (NULL)
  SET NEW.id = CONCAT('YTUM', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 8, '00000'));
END
```

> MySQL said: Documentation 
>   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET NEW.id = CONCAT('YTUM', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 8, '00000'));
>    END' at line 6

Comment: SET can be used with UPDATE query and not INSERT.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the trigger is your problem.

Comment: I changed Insert to Update, no luck.

Comment: Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: use  `;`  after your insert statement and dont forget the DELIMITER

Answer (score 0):

Your Formatting is off, remember `DELIMITER $$` statements are required, as it is no different than creating a stored procedure.

[Check the documentation any time you run into issues like this.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Scroll about half way down the documents to see the example.

But, This is what your looking for:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_newuser_insert 
BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl_newuser
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

        SET NEW.id = CONCAT('YTUM', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 8, '00000'));

    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```